# i need to change the color in my html file

Tags: html

how do i change color if the day = 4?
its supposed to be green when the day is 4, and red else

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
    <h1>Er det Torsdag?</h1>
    <p id="torsdag?"></p>
    </div>

<script>
    {
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Nei";
    weekday[1] = "Nei";
    weekday[2] = "Nei";
    weekday[3] = "Nei";
    weekday[4] = "Ja";
    weekday[5] = "Nei";
    weekday[6] = "Nei";

    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
    document.getElementById("torsdag?").innerHTML = n;
}
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the best is probably to change it in the css, but i dont know if i can wirte script in the css file
sorry for bad english :)

Comment: I think you need to choose one approach and focus on doing it elegantly (with as little code as possible). 
I suggest creating a CSS class which sets the color, and then using JS to add that one classname to the element's `classnames` property when it's Torsdag.

Answer (score 1):

use `document.getElementById("torsdag?").style.color = "red";`

for example:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
    <h1>Er det Torsdag?</h1>
    <p id="torsdag?"></p>
    </div>

<script>
    {
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Nei";
    weekday[1] = "Nei";
    weekday[2] = "Nei";
    weekday[3] = "Nei";
    weekday[4] = "Ja";
    weekday[5] = "Nei";
    weekday[6] = "Nei";

    var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
    document.getElementById("torsdag?").innerHTML = n;
    if (d.getDay() == 3){
    document.getElementById("torsdag?").style.color = "red";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("torsdag?").style.color = "green";
    }
    

    
}
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```